# Spring boot gradle "Could not find or load main class"

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, gradle, jar

i have spring boot application that i want to package to jar. On run
my application "`java -jar app.jar`" i caught error "**Could not find or load main class com.software.appcreator.MyClass**". I use gradle to build app, here is details of my build.gradle file(without dependencies):

https://pastebin.com/MvNgBDua

there are problems with formatting build.gradle, therefore posted on pastebin

what could be the reason for this situation? i pointed out main class in config and MyClass is present in final jar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to run `./gradlew bootRepackage` to generate the executable jar.

ref: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/build-tool-plugins-gradle-plugin.html#build-tool-plugins-gradle-packaging

Comment: I went to your link but the string "bootRepackage" does not exist.  Has the documentation changed?

Answer (score 1):

Does `gradle bootRun` works? You don't need to write your own jar task, the jar file built by the default assemble task should works already.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-running-your-application.html

Answer (score 1):

If anyone facing the same issue, please put the below snippet in your build.gradle and rebuild.

```
springBoot {
    mainClassName = "your.class.Name"
}
```